How to srt observable component in watermelondb
How do I sort observable component in watermelondb. The doc says something like this but the docs outdated and currently the newest watermelondb doesnt have sortWith.

const sortComments = sortWith([
  descend(prop('likes'))
])

const CommentList = ({ comments }) => (
  <div>
    {sortComments(comments).map(comment =>
      <EnhancedComment key={comment.id} comment={comment} />
    )}
  </div>
)

const enhance = withObservables(['post'], ({ post }) => ({
  comments: post.comments.observeWithColumns(['likes'])
}))

const EnhancedCommentList = enhance(CommentList


You can always create a query using withObservables and return the records already sorted:
const enhance = withObservables(['post'], ({ post, database }) => ({
  comments: database
    .get('comments')
    .query(Q.where('post_id', post.id), Q.desc)
    .observeWithColumns(['likes']),
}));

